# How are _init and _new functions different when using an opaque pointer?

Tags: c

I am currently reading Jens Gustedt's book "Modern C". Everything has been illuminating aside from one niggling question that stems from an example about circular buffers.

The code is as follows:

**circular.h**

```
#ifndef CIRCULAR_H
# define CIRCULAR_H 1

# include <stddef.h>
# include <stdio.h>

/** @brief an opaque type for a circular buffer for @c double values
 **
 ** This data structure allows to add @c double values in rear and to
 ** take them out in front. Each such structure has a maximal amount
 ** of elements that can be stored in it.
 **
 **/
typedef struct circular circular;

/**
 ** @name Initialization and destruction
 ** @{
 **/

/** @brief Initialize a circular buffer @a c with maximally @a
 ** max_len elements.
 **
 ** Only use this function on an uninitialized buffer.
 **
 ** Each buffer that is initialized with this function must be
 ** destroyed with a call to ::circular_destroy.
 **/
circular* circular_init(circular* c, size_t max_len);

/** @brief Destroy circular buffer @a c
 **
 ** @a c must have been initialized with a call to ::circular_init
 **/
void circular_destroy(circular* c);

/** @brief Allocate and initialize a circular buffer with maximally
 ** @a len elements.
 **
 ** Each buffer that is allocated with this function must be deleted
 ** with a call to ::circular_delete.
 **/
circular* circular_new(size_t len);

/** @brief Delete circular buffer @a c
 **
 ** @a c must have been allocated with a call to ::circular_new
 **/
void circular_delete(circular* c);
/**
 ** @}
 **/

/**
 ** @name Using elements of a circular
 ** @{
 **/

/** @brief Append a new element with value @a value to the buffer @a c
 **
 ** @return c if the new element could be appended, @c 0 otherwise.
 **/
circular* circular_append(circular* c, double value);

/** @brief Remove the oldest element from @a c and return its value
 **
 ** @return the removed element if it exists, @c 0.0 otherwise.
 **/

double circular_pop(circular* c);

/** @brief Return a pointer to position @a pos in buffer @a c
 **
 ** @return a pointer to element @a pos of the buffer, @c 0 otherwise.
 **/
double* circular_element(circular* c, size_t pos);


/**
 ** @}
 **/

/**
 ** @name Maintain a circular
 ** @{
 **/

/** @brief Return the number of elements stored. */
size_t circular_getlength(circular* c);

/** @brief Resize to capacity @a max_len. */
circular* circular_resize(circular* c, size_t max_len);

/** @brief Print the buffer values to stream @a s. */
void circular_fput(circular* c, FILE* s);

/**
 ** @}
 **/



#endif
```

**circular.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "circular.h"

/** @brief the hidden implementation of the circular buffer type */
struct circular {
  size_t start;    /**< Position of element 0 */
  size_t len;      /**< Number of elements stored */
  size_t max_len;  /**< Maximum capacity */
  double* tab;     /**< Array holding the data */
};

circular* circular_init(circular* c, size_t max_len) {
  if (c) {
    if (max_len) {
      *c = (circular){
        .max_len = max_len,
        .tab = malloc(sizeof(double[max_len])),
      };
        // Allocation failed.
      if (!c->tab) c->max_len = 0;
    } else {
      *c = (circular){ 0 };
    }
  }
  return c;
}

void circular_destroy(circular* c) {
  if (c) {
    free(c->tab);
    circular_init(c, 0);
  }
}

circular* circular_new(size_t len) {
  return circular_init(malloc(sizeof(circular)), len);
}

void circular_delete(circular* c) {
  circular_destroy(c);
  free(c);
}


size_t circular_getlength(circular* c) {
  return c ? c->len : 0;
}

static size_t circular_getpos(circular* c, size_t pos) {
  pos += c->start;
  pos %= c->max_len;
  return pos;
}

circular* circular_append(circular* c, double value) {
  if (c) {
    double* where = circular_element(c, c->len);
    if (where) {
      *where = value;
      ++c->len;
      return c;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

double* circular_element(circular* c, size_t pos) {
  double* ret = 0;
  if (c) {
    if (pos < c->max_len) {
      pos = circular_getpos(c, pos);
      ret = &c->tab[pos];
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

double circular_pop(circular* c) {
  double ret = 0.0;
  if (c && c->len) {
    double* p = circular_element(c, 0);
    if (p) ret = *p;
    ++c->start;
    --c->len;
  }
  return ret;
}



circular* circular_resize(circular* c, size_t nlen) {
  if (c) {
    size_t len = c->len;
    if (len > nlen) return 0;
    size_t olen = c->max_len;
    if (nlen != olen) {
      size_t ostart = circular_getpos(c, 0);
      size_t nstart = ostart;
      double* otab = c->tab;
      double* ntab;
      if (nlen > olen) {
        ntab = realloc(c->tab, sizeof(double[nlen]));
        if (!ntab) return 0;
        // Two separate chunks
        if (ostart+len > olen) {
          size_t ulen = olen - ostart;
          size_t llen = len - ulen;
          if (llen <= (nlen - olen)) {
            /* Copy the lower one up after the old end. */ /*@\label{cpy-lowchunk}*/
            memcpy(ntab + olen, ntab,
                   llen*sizeof(double));
          } else {
            /* Move the upper one up to the new end. */ /*@\label{cpy-hichunk}*/
            nstart = nlen - ulen;
            memmove(ntab + nstart, ntab + ostart,
                    ulen*sizeof(double));
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (ostart+len > olen) {
          // Two separate chunks; mv the upper one down to the new end.
          size_t ulen = olen - ostart;
          nstart = nlen - ulen;
          memmove(otab + nstart, otab + ostart, ulen*sizeof(double));
        } else {
          // A single chunk
          if (ostart + len > nlen) {
            // Reallocation cuts the existing chunk in two.
            memmove(otab, otab + ostart, len*sizeof(double));
            nstart = 0;
          }
        }
        // Now all data is saved in the conserved part of the array.
        ntab = realloc(c->tab, sizeof(double[nlen]));
        // If realloc fails in this case (would be weird), just overrule it.
        if (!ntab) ntab = otab;
      }
      *c = (circular){
        .max_len = nlen,
        .start = nstart,
        .len = len,
        .tab = ntab,
      };
    }
  }
  return c;
}

void circular_fput(circular* c, FILE* s) {
  if (c) {
    size_t len = circular_getlength(c);
    double* tab = c->tab;
    if (tab) {
      fprintf(s, "%p+%zu (%zu+%zu):", (void*)tab, c->max_len, c->start, len);
      for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        fprintf(s, "\t%g", *circular_element(c, i));
      }
      fputc('\n', s);
      return;
    }
  }
  fputs("invalid circular\n", s);
}
```

In the header there exists two functions, `circular_new` and `circular_init`. The former is essentially a wrapper around the latter with a `malloc` call to create space for the `struct circular`.

This makes sense to me as it allows a user of this library to create their own `circular struct` and initialize it themselves, or let `circular_new` do all the work for them. However, I struggle to understand how a user of this library might call `circular_init` without calling `circular_new` as the `struct circular` is an opaque type -- this means that no size information about the structure is known through the header file.

Should `circular_init` be declared static? Is there some way for someone who only has access to the header file to create their own buffer and run `circular_init` on it without calling `circular_new` first?

Comment: *If* `sizeof(circular)` was made available somehow (not the `struct` definition, just its size), then `circular_init` could be used to initialize local variables and/or arrays of `circular` objects.

Comment: So as long as I have the function `circular_struct_size`, I'm able to forego at least one malloc call within the library? That makes sense to me. But it doesn't seem like there's a way to encode that at compile time.

Comment: Right. And the `_init`/`_new` API design suggests that the size would be made available somehow.

Comment: The other guess is that this is supposed to allow reusing the same dynamically allocated object by doing `circular_new` + repeated `circular_destroy/circular_init` + `circular_delete`. But that relies on the assumption that `circular_new` calls `circular_init` internally, and `circular_delete` calls `circular_destroy`. While that'd be the sensible behavior, it is not spelled out in the code comments.